# Mapping data from 2 tables to a single entity

Tags: c#, sql, dapper

I have 2 tables which have one to one relationship.The tables are as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Provider](
[ProviderId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
[FirstName] [varchar](40) NOT NULL,
[LastName] [varchar](40) NOT NULL,
[SSN] [varchar](15) NOT NULL,
[NPI] [varchar](15) NOT NULL,
[ProviderStatus] [bit] NOT NULL)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ProviderDetails](
[ProviderDetailsID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
[Certification] [varchar](40) NOT NULL,
[Specialization] [varchar](40) NOT NULL,
[TaxonomyCode] [varchar](40) NOT NULL,
[ContactNumber] [varchar](15) NOT NULL,
[ContactEmail] [varchar](40) NOT NULL,
[ProviderId]  [int] FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Provider(ProviderId) NOT NULL)
```

I have created 2 entities in C# *(Mind you, I am not using EF)*

```
 public class Provider
{
    public int ProviderID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string SSN { get; set; }
    public string NPI { get; set; }
    public ProviderDetails ProviderDetails { get; set; }
}

public class ProviderDetails
{
    public int ProviderDetailsId { get; set; }
    public string Certification { get; set; }
    public string Specialization { get; set; }
    public string TaxonomyCode { get; set; }
    public string ContactNumber { get; set; }
    public string ContactEmail { get; set; }
    public int ProviderId { get; set; }
}
```

I, earlier had a single entity, Provider. So, I was able to get the list of providers to display with the following code.

```
    public List<Provider> GetListofProviders()
    {
        List<Provider> Providers = new List<Provider>();
        using (_dbConnection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DemoApplicationConnection"].ConnectionString))
        {
            try
            {
                Providers = (List<Provider>)(_dbConnection.Query<Provider>("spGetAllProviders", commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure));
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
        } 
        return Providers;
    }
```

To get data from the database, I am using the following query:

```
ALTER PROC [dbo].[spGetAllProviders]
AS
SELECT * FROM Provider 
INNER JOIN ProviderDetails 
ON Provider.ProviderId = ProviderDetails .ProviderId
WHERE Provider.ProviderStatus = 1
```

Since I have split the entities, could someone please guide me on how I would map the data from the database to the 2 entities?

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to solve this problem:

Write two separate stored procedures to pull the data from each individual table then load them into their respective objects: Provider and ProviderDetails.

The simplest way I can think to use would be to return a DataTable from the stored proc. You can then access each individual node in the Datatable by utilizing a foreach loop. Your stored procedure call would look something like this.

```
public DataTable GetListofProviders()
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    SqlCommand cmd = New SqlCommand("spGetAllProviders");
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(_dbConnection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DemoApplicationConnection"].ConnectionString);
    using(cn)
    {
        Try
        {
            SqlDataAdapter da = New SqlDataAdapter(cmd, cn);
            da.Fill(dt);
        }
        Catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            throw ex.Message;
        }
    }

    return dt;
}
```

That may not be 100% correct, but it's close. After you return the datatable, you can call a function to load each object into a list. this will look a bit like this:

Also note that these lists should be passed by reference into the loading function.

```
public void LoadObjects(ref List<Provider> providers, ref List<ProviderDetail> providerDetail)
{
  DataTable dt = GetListofProviders();
  Provider p = New Provider();
  ProviderDetail pd = new ProviderDetail();
  if(dt.rows.count > 0)
  {
      For Each(DataRow dr in dt)
      {
          p.ProviderID = dr.Item["ProviderId"].ToInt32();
          p.FirstName = dr.Item["FirstName"].ToString();
          .....continue to load object and add it to list
          providers.Add(p);

          pd.ProviderDetailsID = dr.Item["ProviderDetailsID"].ToInt32();
          pd.Certification = dr.Item["Certification"].ToString();
          .....continue to load object and add it to list
          providerDetails.Add(pd);
      }
  }
  else
  {
       ...do something else
  }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Now this is not the right answer.But I think this would be the way to go about.Although its not working for me.So,if someone could tell me what I am doing wrong,would be really helpful.

```
public List<Provider> GetListofProviders()
{
   List<Provider> Providers = new List<Provider>();
   using (_dbConnection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DemoApplicationConnection"].ConnectionString))
   {
       try
       {
          Providers = _dbConnection.Query<Provider,ProviderDetails,Provider>("spGetAllProviders",null,splitOn: "ProviderId", commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure).ToList();
       }
       catch (Exception)
       {
         throw;
       }
   } 
   return Providers;
}
```

Also the stored procedure is

```
ALTER PROC [dbo].[spGetAllProviders]
AS
SELECT Provider.*,
       ProviderDetails.ProviderId,
       ProviderDetails.ProviderDetailsID,
       ProviderDetails.Certification,
       ProviderDetails.Specialization,
       ProviderDetails.TaxonomyCode,
       ProviderDetails.ContactNumber,
       ProviderDetails.ContactEmail 
FROM Provider 
INNER JOIN ProviderDetails 
ON Provider.ProviderId = ProviderDetails .ProviderId
WHERE Provider.ProviderStatus = 1
```

I am getting the following error.

When using the multi-mapping APIs ensure you set the splitOn param if you have keys other than Id